# round php decimal value to second digit after last 0

Tags: php, rounding

I have results of an "on the fly" calculation that end in decimal values (after converted using money_format) as follows:

```
$cost_per_trans  = 0.0000000476 

$cost_per_trans = 0.0000007047
```

The corresponding values before the money_format are:

```
4.7564687975647E-8

7.0466204408366E-7
```

These values may be of different lengths but I would like to be able to round them to the last 2 digits after the string of "0s", to get this for example:

```
$cost_per_trans = 0.000000048 

$cost_per_trans = 0.00000070
```

I am unsure of

1. how to do the round in the right spot?
2. whether to round before or after the money_format?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php#24379

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I rely on PHP php.ini precision workaround for floating point issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587290/can-i-rely-on-php-php-ini-precision-workaround-for-floating-point-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function format_to_last_2_digits($number) {
    $depth = 0;
    $test = $number;
    while ($test < 10) {    // >10 means we have enough depth
        $test = $test * 10;
        $depth += 1;
    }
    return number_format($number, $depth);
}

$cost_per_trans = 0.0000000476;
var_dump(format_to_last_2_digits($cost_per_trans)); // 0.000000048
$high_number = 300;
var_dump(format_to_last_2_digits($high_number));    // 300
```

Comment: There is an error in your code: line 2 sets `$depth` to zero, so it becomes useless.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Question though, why the "$high_number" value?

Comment: To show that it works for any number, even a number that has more than 2 decimals already. @silkfire's regexp solution wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Your rounding method is very specific. Try this:

```
function exp2dec($number) {
   preg_match('#(.*)E-(.*)#', str_replace('.', '', $number), $matches);
   $num = '0.';

   while ($matches[2] > 1) {
      $num .= '0';
      $matches[2]--;
   }

   return $num . $matches[1];
}


$cost_per_trans = 0.0000000476;

preg_match('#^(0\.0+)([^0]+)$#', exp2dec($cost_per_trans), $parts);

$rounded_value = $parts[1] . str_replace('0.', '', round('0.' . $parts[2], 2));
```

Comment: Thanks silkfire. For some reasosn though, if I try to use just "$rounded_value" I get string(11) "00000000.48"

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Adjusted the code appropriately with a custom function. Notice that the input number must be a float, not a string.