# PHP Round unexpected result

Tags: php, rounding

I have a problem with php round function. Rounds function not working correctly:

```
$value = 562.92578125;

round($value,1); // return 562.9 (correctly)
round($value,2); // return 562.9299999999999 (wrong)
round($value,3); // return 562.926 (correctly)
```

Comment: Is this all of the code you are working with because the round function works properly?

Comment: I have found the problem, an included class (php excel) return me unexpected value from round function. An updated version of this class return a correctly result of round function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround try to use:

```
number_format(round($value, 1), 1);
number_format(round($value, 2), 2);
number_format(round($value, 3), 3);
```

Also, have a look here: [Can I rely on PHP php.ini precision workaround for floating point issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587290/can-i-rely-on-php-php-ini-precision-workaround-for-floating-point-issue)

Comment: It's a good trick, i found the problem (phpexcel), but i can not update the library class.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine,

```
$value = 562.92578125;

round($value,1); // return 562.9
round($value,2); // return 562.93
round($value,3); // return 562.926
```

See [demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e140e30100f39c860d85fd8a1f30decc8181c8e7)