# How can use big float number in PHP?

Tags: php, floating-point

I have this number :

```
0.953163394286767
```

I assign this number to float variables.

```
$vari = (float)$appo;
```

But if i print i obtain :

```
0.95316339428677
```

How can resolve this problem?

Comment: what result you want?

Comment: I want the first result 0.953163394286767

Comment: Use [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).

Comment: Nope, just follow the link. bcmath is a library that stores floating point values in strings and allows you to calculate with any precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function here.

```
ini_set('precision', 16);
$appo =  0.953163394286767;
echo $vari = (float)$appo;//prints 0.953163394286767
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Note that this cannot be set arbitrarily high. In fact, according to the PHP documentarion on floats, [16 digits seem to be the maximum sensible value](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.float.php). Also have a look at this [demo](https://eval.in/534760). There is also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587290/can-i-rely-on-php-php-ini-precision-workaround-for-floating-point-issue?rq=1 which discusses the problem in depth.