# PHP prevent float round

Tags: php

I have a scenario here where I need to perform a few calculations and I need the exact float number not the rounded float number. For e.g this is the float I want `51.8385922330097`, which rounds of to `51.83859223301`. So any idea how to prevent this auto round of in PHP?

Comment: Short answer: That's how [floats work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), deal with it. Long answer: Use an [arbitrary precision library](https://php-decimal.io/#introduction).

Comment: The 'exact float number' is a myth born of of the workings of floating point representation. What you need is [BCMath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point numbers have a limited accuracy, you shoudl check this PHP Doc article:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

**This might help you:**
[How can use big float number in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938970/how-can-use-big-float-number-in-php/35939179)

If you wish to dive into the scientific reasons, this is a pretty good explanation:
[Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: Increasing `precision` value in `php.ini` worked for now. ini_set('precision', 16);