# Why does setting 'precision' break php round()?

Tags: php, precision

Recently came across a situation where I was working on a server that had a php.ini file with:

```
precision = 16
```

The default being 14, this seems harmless enough.  Unfortunately it lead to this:

```
// ini_set('precision', 16);
echo round((20.12 / 36.79),4);
```

**Result:** `0.5469000000000001`

Huh?  Shouldn't `round()` be taking care of the floating point precision issues here?

Comment: err, what..? can mention the php version?

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter as it's a float precision issue.  Tested and same result php 5.3 - php 7.0

Comment: ah i see, looks like we missed the concept of truncating vs rounding.. well [some discussion on floating points](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14656315/4648586)

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept - I just (wrongly) assumed that `round()` would take care of business here.  I guess as long as it's returning a float it will be prone to this kind of behavior.

Comment: [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) returns a float, and that float still has a margin of error if you turn up the display precision high enough to see it. If you want to format a number for display then you need to use something like [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). Also, if you're dealing with money you need to not use floats *at all*.

Comment: @Sammitch - That makes sense, however neither of those functions actually round - in the end I'm first rounding, then truncating which gives the desired result.

Comment: it may help someone reading these comments to know that `number_format()` takes care of rounding and returns a string so is not subject to float issues.  I wrongly assumed that `number_format()` only truncates but it actually rounds properly as well.  e.g., `number_format(1.237,2) == "1.24"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php's [`round()`](http://php.net/round) function still returns a floating point number, not a string, so it might be inexact.

`0.5469` is presented as the following 8 bytes `0x3FE180346DC5D639` encoded double precision IEEE754.

Which is not the exact representation of `0.5469` but a closest representible number, which actually is `5.46900000000000052757798130187E-1`

References:

- [0.5469 to bin](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=048046053052054057)
- [0x3FE180346DC5D639 to dec](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=3FE180346DC5D639)