# Measuring the execution time of any piece of code in PHP, getting negative result

Tags: php, execution-time

I'm trying to profile some piece of php code by computing the time in microseconds it takes it to execute. I have created a profiler function that take another function as parameter like this

```php
function profiler($funct) 
{
    $raw_start_time = microtime();
    $funct();
    $raw_end_time = microtime();

    $start_time = 1000000 * (double) explode(" ", $raw_start_time)[0];
    $end_time = 1000000 * (double) explode(" ", $raw_end_time)[0];

    return $end_time - $start_time;
}
```

I use my `profiler()` function like this

```php
$duration = profiler(function() {
                //code i want to profile
            });

echo $duration;
```

The function runs correctly most times and returns the correct time duration of execution. However, I get negative values in some test cases. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic seems to be a [hassle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587290/can-i-rely-on-php-php-ini-precision-workaround-for-floating-point-issue), so I'm trying to avoid it as much as possible.

The problem with the OP code was that only the *microseconds* part of the result was used. Consequently, if duration of the execution exceeds one second, the end result can be a negative difference.

The solution that worked for me was to substring the *microseconds* part (to eliminate the leading zero) and join that to the end of *seconds* part. Finally, everything is converted to *microseconds* by multiplying by *1000000*.

```php
function profiler($funct) 
{
    $raw_start_time = microtime();
    $funct();
    $raw_end_time = microtime();

    $array_start_time = explode(" ", $raw_start_time);
    $start_time = (int) (1000000 * (double) implode("", [$array_start_time[1], substr($array_start_time[0], 1, 8)]));

    $array_end_time = explode(" ", $raw_end_time);
    $end_time = (int) (1000000 * (double) implode("", [$array_end_time[1], substr($array_end_time[0], 1, 8)]));

    return $end_time - $start_time;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`microtime ([ bool $get_as_float = FALSE ] ) : mixed`
try set it to TRUE

From my point of view next happening. You get result in form "msec sec" and use only msec. When Time of execution more that ~500msec. Result is negative

If you don't want use float than use next approach

`$start_time = explode(" ", $raw_start_time)[1] * 1000 + explode(" ", $raw_start_time)[0];`

and same thing with end_time.

If `microtime(FALSE)` you will NOT get microseconds. Only millis. Micros woth TRUE

Comment: I want to avoid the use of decimal points in the result as much as possible. I want whole number microsecond value.

Comment: As far as I know there is no PHP function that returns MICROseconds not as real value. And that's pretty logical. Because it's very long "int"

Comment: Look also at `gettimeofday` maybe that's what you need